# Word 2016 VBA: can't find EndOfDoc when cursor is in footnote

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

I made a search-&-replace macro that loops to the end of the document, like so:

```
Sub CheckEnglishAndTypos()
    Do Until ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Sel").Range.End = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.End
    'Loop the search till the end
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "(<*>) \1"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Loop
        ' Searching the remaning (till the end of document)
        Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Problem is, if the document has any footnote, and the search move into the footnote, it will then give a "Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist" error. Apparently, the macro can't find the end of the document if the selection/cursor is inside a footnote, and the document has pages following the page the footnote's at.

Is there anyway to fix it? A way to exclude the footnotes from search would be cool, but I'm open to any other alternative solutions.

Comment: why do you have `Exit Sub` at the end of the sub?

Comment: Forgot that was there lol. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the search string is the issue

```
Sub CheckEnglishAndTypos()

    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBlue
'   Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
'       .Text = "(<*>) \1"                ' really slow
        .Text = " ([A-Za-z]@) \1"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should do the whole document

```
Sub CheckEnglishAndTypos()

    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBlue
'   Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "(<*>) \1"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: My documents are usually 300+ pages, and unless I limit the thing to go by paragraph, it will take an entire day to run.

Comment: is it faster "by paragraph" ?

Comment: took roughly 1 hour to get the job done, so about 24 times faster. Probably because it didn't have to match words that are light year apart

Comment: i thought that it searches for doubled up words

Comment: how long does the search take when started from the "advanced find" dialog?

Comment: it's the same, an entire day. When I pressed esc mid way, it highlighted the entire document. Could this be related?

Comment: **does anybody know the reason for this?**